# db_select with join, union and add columns with null values

Tags: database

I try to extend the search functionality and want to search in the node AND users table. For this I need new columns with NULL values. How can I do this?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT uid, name, mail, login AS date, picture, NULL AS nid, NULL AS type, NULL AS title, NULL AS status, NULL AS word, NULL AS score FROM users
  UNION (SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, changed AS date, NULL, nid, node.type, title, status, word, score FROM search_index JOIN node ON search_index.sid = node.nid)
) AS Result 
ORDER BY Result.date ASC;
```

---

Now I have another problem with this query. After solving the problem with the NULL values the columns are sort in wrong order. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Sorry, what's your question? Are you trying to turn the above query into a `db_select()`? If so, don't bother...just run the query string through `db_query()`, it'll save you a lot of headaches

Comment: If I turn the query into db_query I can't use the Extender (PagerDefault). Or is there a workaround?

Comment: Not that I know of, no. Have a look at the `where()` and `addExpr()` methods, they allow you to add arbitrary SQL into a `db_select()`.

Comment: Into a db_select, but not in db_query.

Comment: Yes, so use those methods with a `db_select()`, not a `db_query()`, to construct your complex query

Comment: I would do this, but I don't know how to add columns with NULL values. If I try to do this with addField I get an error message, that the number of columns are different. Any idea?

Comment: Yes...use `addExpression()` (sorry it's not `addExpr()` after all)